# how to tansform dataframe correct?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

i want to transform input dataframe to output.
in the output, each row is separated by the input's ST, ED columns.

input

| ST | ED | TYPE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 201501 | 201503 | A |
| 201502 | 201504 | B |
| 201502 | 201505 | C |

output

| ST | ED | TYPE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 201501 | 201501 | A |
| 201502 | 201503 | A,B,C |
| 201504 | 201504 | B,C |
| 201505 | 201505 | C |

i think, below the transformed data, the number of item in each columns is 1/3/2/1. which is similar with the number of item of TYPE's in output.

```
201501 201502 201503 A

201502 201503 201504 B

201502 201503 201504 201505 C
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try (assuming the `df` is sorted):

```py
from itertools import groupby


vals = {}

for a, b, t in zip(df.ST, df.ED, df.TYPE):
    for i in range(a, b+1):
        vals.setdefault(i, set()).add(t)

out = []
for k, g in groupby(sorted(vals.items()), lambda k: k[1]):
    g = list(g)
    out.append({
        'ST': g[0][0],
        'ED': g[-1][0],
        'TYPE': ','.join(sorted(k))
    })

df_out = pd.DataFrame(out)
print(df_out)
```

Prints:

```
       ST      ED   TYPE
0  201501  201501      A
1  201502  201503  A,B,C
2  201504  201504    B,C
3  201505  201505      C
```